# Is this a correct use of ``memory_order_relaxed``?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

I am starting to use (sparingly) the atomic primitives introduced in C++11. A very simple use case is that of using `std::atomic<integral>` in a global `settings` class that stores the runtime configuration of my application.

This class has a bunch of static methods to access global variables initialised at program startup. Previously the access to these global variables was protected by a `mutex`:

```
#include <mutex>

class settings
{
    static unsigned get_n_threads()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(s_mutex);
        return s_n_threads;
    }
    static std::mutex s_mutex;
    static unsigned   s_n_threads;
};
```

With `std::atomic`, I have now:

```
#include <atomic>

class settings
{
    static unsigned get_n_threads()
    {
        return s_n_threads.load();
    }
    static std::atomic<unsigned> s_n_threads;
};
```

Now, I was reading about the memory order specifications for atomic operations here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

It seems like for this very trivial use case scenario, I could modify the `load()` call to this:

```
return s_n_threads.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Note that the only requirement here is that the operations of inspecting and/or changing a global setting have to be atomic. These operations are not part of any lock-free algorithm and they do not need to be sequenced with anything (at least currently).

From some research I have done, it looks like the consensus is to avoid relaxed operations unless one is an expert (which evidently I am not :), so I was wondering which pitfall (if any) I could fall into by applying this change.

Comment: Every expert once was not an expert.

Comment: Your choices for load are `seq_cst`, `acquire`, `consume`, and `relaxed`. Since you don't need the loads to be globally ordered or sequenced, `seq_cst` may be too heavy. `acquire` seems to not fit the bill here since you're not trying to guarantee a synchronizes-with relationship with another store-`release`, nor are you guarding memory reorders that are beyond the load that might float up across it. `consume` is for data dependencies and relies on a store-release/seq_cst and in all compilers I know of is promoted to `acquire`. `relaxed` seems to be your best bet here

Comment: I'm wondering how a client of this class is supposed to change the setting. I might be missing something, but every member of your classes is `private`, yet in your question you mention "changing a global setting". On the other hand, if it is read-only, once the program is running, you do not need any synchronization at all, right?